# Opening a pfring from Go: pfring NewRing error: no such device

Tags: go, pf-ring

I want to call pf_ring from Go code using the `github.com/google/gopacket/pfring` package and cannot get it working on a Debian 11 (my code is working on Debian 10).

This is my Go code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pfring"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    _, err := pfring.NewRing("eno1@0", 1574, pfring.FlagPromisc|pfring.Flag(1<<14))
    if err == nil {
        log.Printf("Success!")
        return
    }
    log.Fatalf("Failure: %s", err)
}
```

And when I run it:

```
# ./test-go 
2023/01/24 10:12:25 Failure: pfring NewRing error: no such device
```

Obviously the eno1 interface exists:

```
# pf_ringcfg --list-interfaces
Name: eno1                 Driver: i40e       RSS:     12   [Supported by ZC]
Name: enp3s0f1             Driver: i40e       RSS:     12   [Supported by ZC]
Name: enx0a229512eeb9      Driver: cdc_ether  RSS:     1    [Linux Driver]
```

The odd thing is that the same code written in C works:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pfring.h>

int main() {
    pfring* ring = pfring_open("eno1@0", 1574, PF_RING_PROMISC | PF_RING_ZC_NOT_REPROGRAM_RSS);
    if (ring != NULL) {
        printf("Success!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    int e = errno;
    char* msg = strerror(e);
    printf("Failure %d: %s\n", e, msg);
    exit(1);
}
```

```
# ./test-c 
Success!
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in gopacket/pfring, see [issue #147](https://github.com/google/gopacket/issues/147) and the [fix](https://github.com/google/gopacket/pull/1087). The call to `pfring_open` made by this library reported no error, but the library misinterpreted the return code.